# How do I get the User ID Token from a Credential object?

Tags: java, google-oauth, google-api-java-client

I have been following [this](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/java) tutorial to include Google Sign-in support to my Desktop app. The library I'm using is [this one](https://github.com/google/google-api-java-client).

Everything works and this is the implementation of the `authorize()` method:

```
public Credential authorize() throws IOException {
    // Load client secrets.
    InputStream in = GoogleLogin.class.getResourceAsStream("/google/client_secret.json");
    GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets = GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY, new InputStreamReader(in));

    // Build flow and trigger user authorization request.
    GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
            HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets, SCOPES)
            .setDataStoreFactory(DATA_STORE_FACTORY)
            .setAccessType("offline")
            .build();

    Credential credential = new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow, new LocalServerReceiver()).authorize("user");

    System.out.println("Credentials saved to " + DATA_STORE_DIR.getAbsolutePath());
    return credential;
}
```

However, from a `Credential` object, I can only retrieve the access token by calling `Credential.getAccessToken()`, but what I need is the `id token`. How can I retrieve the id_token from the user after it's been authenticated?

Comment: @burrito77 Please, read the question before commenting. This isn't Android and I'm not using the library that person is using.

Comment: It doesn't help me because it's LITERALLY another platform. Android libraries for OAuth2 aren't compatible with Java installed apps. Thank you, but it really doesn't help.

Comment: I am well aware... just thought that it could help at least a bit as they are similar problems

Comment: @burrito77 Again, thank you for at least trying, and I apologise for snapping. I've been at this for hours and I can't find answers anywhere.

Comment: I'll add a bounty if you don't get an ans after 2 days

Comment: gl(2 days is the min)

Comment: @burrito77 I'd appreciate that very much. Thank you, burrito.

Comment: just to make sure, you still haven't found an answer yet?

Comment: No, I haven't =(

Comment: @burrito77 I figured it out!!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I literally figured it out after starting the bounty! It's possible to get the Id Token by inheriting from `AuthorizedCodeInstalledApp` and providing your own implementation of `authorize()`

Here's what I did...

```
public class GoogleAuthCodeInstalledApp extends AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp {

    public GoogleAuthCodeInstalledApp(AuthorizationCodeFlow flow, VerificationCodeReceiver receiver) {
        super(flow, receiver);
    }

    @Override
    public Credential authorize(String userId) throws IOException {
        try {
            Credential credential = getFlow().loadCredential(userId);
            if (credential != null
                    && (credential.getRefreshToken() != null
                    || credential.getExpiresInSeconds() == null
                    || credential.getExpiresInSeconds() > 60)) {
                return credential;
            }
            // open in browser
            String redirectUri = getReceiver().getRedirectUri();
            AuthorizationCodeRequestUrl authorizationUrl
                    = getFlow().newAuthorizationUrl().setRedirectUri(redirectUri);
            onAuthorization(authorizationUrl);
            // receive authorization code and exchange it for an access token
            String code = getReceiver().waitForCode();
            GoogleTokenResponse response = (GoogleTokenResponse) getFlow().newTokenRequest(code).setRedirectUri(redirectUri).execute();
            System.out.println(response.getIdToken()); //YES, THIS IS THE ID TOKEN!!!
            // store credential and return it
            return getFlow().createAndStoreCredential(response, userId);
        } finally {
            getReceiver().stop();
        }
    }

}
```

After you do that, instead of

```
Credential credential = new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow, new LocalServerReceiver()).authorize("user");
```

Use:

```
Credential credential = new GoogleAuthCodeInstalledApp(flow, new LocalServerReceiver()).authorize("user");
```

#### **UPDATE 2018-05-29 - I have found a better, more reliable solution**

This solution I found works by adding a `CredentialCreatedListener` and a `CredentialRefreshListener` inside our `GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder`.

Here's the sample code:

```
public Credential authorize() throws IOException {
    InputStream in = GoogleLogin.class.getResourceAsStream("/google/client_secret.json");
    GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets = GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY, new InputStreamReader(in));
    // Build flow and trigger user authorization request.
    flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
            HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets, SCOPES)
            .setDataStoreFactory(DATA_STORE_FACTORY)
            .setAccessType("offline")
            .setCredentialCreatedListener(new AuthorizationCodeFlow.CredentialCreatedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCredentialCreated(Credential credential, TokenResponse tokenResponse) throws IOException {
                    DATA_STORE_FACTORY.getDataStore("user").set("id_token", tokenResponse.get("id_token").toString());
                }
            })
            .addRefreshListener(new CredentialRefreshListener() {
                @Override
                public void onTokenResponse(Credential credential, TokenResponse tokenResponse) throws IOException {
                    DATA_STORE_FACTORY.getDataStore("user").set("id_token", tokenResponse.get("id_token").toString());
                }

                @Override
                public void onTokenErrorResponse(Credential credential, TokenErrorResponse tokenErrorResponse) throws IOException {
                    //handle token error response
                }
            })
            .build();

    Credential credential = new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow, serverReceiver).authorize("user");
    System.out.println("Credentials saved to " + DATA_STORE_DIR.getAbsolutePath());
    return credential;
}
```

The code is pretty much self-explanatory. Whenever a new `Credential` is created or refreshed by calling `credential.refreshToken()`, the listeners will be notified and the `id_token` will be taken from the `TokenResponse` (which is actually a `GoogleTokenResponse` object that contains an `id_token` field), and we'll use the default `DataStoreFactory` to save the `id_token`. The `id_token` will now be persisted locally, and will be automatically updated by the listeners whenever `credential.refreshToken()` is called.

Comment: Thank you for this--it's exactly what I need.  Do I need to be concerned with sharing the client secret within the app though?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19615372/client-secret-in-oauth-2-0#answer-36830438 indicates I don't, but there aren't any official references to back it up.

Comment: Just found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51399187/oauth2-with-desktop-application-security#answer-51401257 which points out the risks of sharing your client secret for installed desktop apps.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4419915/how-to-keep-the-oauth-consumer-secret-safe-and-how-to-react-when-its-compromis#answer-4419966 is another great answer too.

Comment: calling credential.refreshToken() does not seem to refresh the id_token...  maybe it's my implementation though...

Comment: Just want to add. Make sure you included "openid" in scopes

Comment: @Morgan what is DATA_STORE_FACTORY kindly tell me i am new so i dont know about it and how i get this value and set it