# OAuth2 with Desktop Application Security

Tags: security, oauth-2.0, google-drive-api, electron, desktop

I have an Electron application that's basically a Google Drive client. I am planning to use OAuth 2.

However, Google API requires me to register my application where a client_secret is generated. Since this is a desktop application, I have my client_secret stored in a server. The authentication URL is generated in the server and sent to the user.

I'm worried that people can pretend to be the app and do things on behalf of my client_secret. If someone with malicious intent creates an unauthorized app and sends requests to my server, they could theoretically do malicious things on my application's behalf.

Is there anything I can do to mitigate this problem or is this not an issue?

edit: People will only access their own files. Just like they would on drive.google.com (read/write/delete files)

Comment: Can you update your question to explain who the users are and what Drive resources the app will be accessing (eg. their own or somebody else's)

Comment: @pinoyyid, updated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Edit:** **Verifying that a request came from your desktop application and not a clone of it to your server is not really possible** unless you control the locations where it is installed, but for a user program you don't. You can place some meagre barriers, but you can't provide any guarantees. It looks like iOS/Android are moving on this front, I imagine the only viable implementation would be for the OS to send a verified credential on your behalf, that is OS level support, not application level support.

As for general OAuth 2.0 authentication methods...

If we go through the motions here, we can analyse each method of authorisation and take a look at the risk of this. https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2

1. https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer (I think you're in this camp, but there's no `client_secret` here)

   - **Only risk of DOS against your client credentials.** The responses are only ever acknowledged and forwarded to the specified redirect Uri, so requests can be made on your behalf for tokens, but only your server will ever receive the tokens (assuming the user agent is decent), you should deal with the case where you receive unknown token responses.
2. https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2InstalledApp

   - **Risk of User installing a malicious app.** When you lose the `client_id`, `client_secret` and the `redirectUri` (you have no way to keep these private against debugging of the device), then anybody will be able to make apps on your behalf. This is an unfortunate problem for mobile apps. The only defence is the User consent screen for now, that is, hopefully the User notices by looking at the consent screen that they have been duped into installing a malicious app from the store instead of your legitimate app.

     I'd love to see some more work on this front, perhaps the App Stores could hold some credentials on your behalf and then confirm that it is your app requesting, I imagine that would involve some hash checking etc.

     *I'd be even happier to be corrected on this one, but I see nothing preventing the above problem :P*
3. https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2UserAgent

   - **Same as 1.**
4. https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ForDevices

   - **Same as 2.**

Comment: Perhaps this is the wrong angle actually, reading your question again :D I'll leave it here for general purposes...

Comment: And I've edited to answer what I think was the original question, unfortunately the answer is, you can't...

Comment: For the 2nd option, the API ID and client secret is stored inside the program. 

Could I get banned because the malicious actor can abuse Google TOS with my client_secret and API ID on their own malicious program?

also, what is the point of the client_secret in the 2nd option considering its not even secret and the api id is identifying the application?

Comment: it´s called a "secret" for a reason. Yes Google could take steps, and rightly so. When users grant permissions to an app using OAuth, they are granting them to the client ID. With your client secret, a malicious actor could create malware that has the same permissions as your original code.

Comment: @Nigel You could take pinoyyid's suggestion below, but really if it's an Electron app you have access to some web view aye? So I would just do Flow 1 or 3 all in app and forget the `client_secret`, you can tie in the server with the request made from the app by using the `state` parameter :P

Comment: Although you'd have to make that unspoofable, which may or may not be doable...There is no point in the `client_secret` in option 2, there's not much point in it at all imo, which is my most services don't issue them

Answer (score 1):

Personally I would create a proxy service which mimics the Google Drive REST API, but implements your own AAA mechanisms. That way all of the secrets are secured on the server and you can add fine-grained access control.